# How to distort (in this case) letters, patterns etc underneath a water drop?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, mesh, materials, distort

I’m interested on how to distort typography, patterns etc. which partially lie underneath a drop of liquid. See example below.

[image: Water with typography]

How would you approach this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image: final]

It's as simple as you wrote about it. Create a drop of fluid and place it on your textured mesh or just mesh with modeled pattern.

You can create drop of fluid with box modeling, sculpting, fluid simulation or even soft body. It's completely up to you.

**Scene setup:**

Nothing more than a **plane** and fluid drop - in this case sculpted with mouse from a **sphere**.

[image: scene]

**Node setup:**

Even simpler - **Principled** shader with **Transmission** set to 1, **IOR**: 1.33 and **Roughness**: 0.

[image: shader]

Comment: Just as an addition to the modeling techniques above: meta objects are also pretty handy and quick for water droplets

Comment: As for the node setup - you can just use the glass BDSF. Any chance it would be faster?

Comment: @JohnDvorak I've did some tests and the differences are in milliseconds for simple scene (GPU rendering). Maybe in more complex setup this could make a difference but for this exact question it seems to be just a matter of taste.